# Getting an Attribute of a Child Class Crashes the Simulation

Tags: c++, omnet++

In my OMNeT++ code, I want an Egg class to inherit from Chicken. Having said that, in my Chicken class I want to get a pointer to the Egg and work with it.

The following code crashes when Qtenvironment starts, saying `Simulation terminated with exit code: 139`

**ChickenEggNetwork.ned**

```
package chickenegg.simulations;

import chickenegg.Chicken;
import chickenegg.Egg;

network ChickenEggNetwork {
    submodules:
        chicken: Chicken;
        egg: Egg;
}
```

**Chicken.ned**

```
package chickenegg;

simple Chicken {
    @class(Chicken);
}
```

**Chicken.h**

```
#ifndef CHICKEN_H_
#define CHICKEN_H_

#include <omnetpp.h>
class Egg;  // forward declaration

class Chicken : public omnetpp::cSimpleModule {
private:
    void initialize(void);
    Egg* egg;  // Get a pointer to Egg class
};

#endif /* CHICKEN_H_ */
```

**Chicken.cc**

```
#include "Chicken.h"
#include "Egg.h"

Define_Module(Chicken);

void Chicken::initialize(void) {
    EV << "Hi, I am a chicken, I am " << egg->eggAge*100 << " days old \n";
}
```

**Egg.ned**

```
package chickenegg;

simple Egg extends Chicken {
    @class(Egg);
}
```

**Egg.h**

```
#ifndef EGG_H_
#define EGG_H_

#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "Chicken.h"

class Egg : public Chicken {
private:
    void initialize(void);
public:
    int eggAge = 2;
};

#endif /* EGG_H_ */
```

**Egg.cc**

```
#include "Egg.h"

Define_Module(Egg);

void Egg::initialize(void) {
    EV << "Hi, I am an egg, I am " << eggAge << " days old \n";
}
```

Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems you never initialise the member egg. Dereferencing it therefore will be dereferencing either a garbage/null pointer (can't remember if it is automatically initialised to 0), which most definetely will cause UB, in most cases handled by a segfault. I am not sure because I am not  100% on how omnet++ handles these things

Comment: @Lala5th How could I circumvent the error?

Comment: `egg->eggAge*100` -- You failed to show when `egg` actually points to somewhere valid.  Without `egg` pointing to an `Egg` object, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But I have pointed `egg` to `Egg` in **Chicken.h** by saying `Egg* egg`, or?

Comment: @Python Initialise `egg` to point to an `Egg`. Either via `new Egg()` somewhere or something else. As  to you pointed `egg` to `Egg`, that is not how the language works. `Egg* egg` simply means that `*egg` is of type `Egg` i.e. `egg` is a pointer to an`Egg` instance, but it is no more than a memory address. If you don't make sure that there is an `Egg` where `egg` is pointing then the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Python -- That's not how C++ works.  You declare a pointer, that's all you did.  Putting the declaration of a pointer inside a class does nothing.  You still need to point that pointer somewhere valid.  This is fundamental C++.

Comment: @Lala5th, PaulMcKenize you are right! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One mustn't create an instance of a class of simple module. According [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:module-ctor):

> Simple modules are never instantiated by the user directly, but rather by the simulation kernel.

If you want to obtain an access to module `egg` from `chicken`, in the code of `Chicken` use the following piece of code:

```
// in Chicken.cc
cModule *mod = getModuleByPath("^.egg");  // ^ means the parent module
if (mod) {
   egg = dynamic_cast<Egg*> (mod);
   if (egg) {
      EV << "Hi, I am a chicken, I am " << egg->eggAge * 100 << " days old \n";
   }
}
```

Reference:
[Finding Modules by Path](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:finding-modules-by-path)

Answer (score 0):

As Lala5th and PaulMcKenize in the comments suggested, adding `egg = new Egg();` in `void Chicken::initialize(void)` method in **Chicken.cc** solved the issue.

Comment: Quick thing to note here: Using `new` without `delete` causes a memory leak, so you'd have to be careful with how you use this. I recommend replacing `Egg* egg` with `std::shared_ptr<Egg> egg` and `new Egg()` with `std::make_shared<Egg>()` or `unique_ptr` and `make_unique` if that's better suited, to offload this problem to the stl.